# error: Cannot set properties of undefined when setting the value of nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set the value of `errors` to

```
{
  email: {
    primary:"abc@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

After compile, it returns an error:

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'primary')
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const newErrors = errors;
    newErrors.email.primary = "abc@gmail.com";
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-http-w0mue?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `newErrors.email` is `undefined`. Just update like this:

```
newErrors.email = { primary: "abc@gmail.com" };
```